# Get the difference between 2 cobertura reports

Tags: java, diff, cobertura

I have a cobertura report for unit tests and another cobertura report for integration tests.
I would like to get the difference between the 2 (more specifically, I would like to know what integration tests are not covered by my unit tests).

Is there a way to get the diff between two cobertura reports?